# LARAVEL - PASAR DATOS DE UNA TABLA A TODAS LAS VISTAS

Tags: php, laravel

estoy haciendo una página de publicaciones.
En mi plantilla principal, la que heredan el resto, tengo un menú lateral con las categorías de las publicaciones, estas categorías son cogidas de la tabla categorías.

En un principio, las introducía manualmente pero encontré una solución mediante el método boot del **AppServiceProvider** en el que guardo todos los registros de la tabla en una variable y se la paso a todas las vistas.

Esto funciona pero **da error** cuando esta tabla no existe, por lo tanto si quiero cargar el proyecto en otra máquina tengo que comentar mi código del método **boot**, realizar la migración y despues descomentarlo.

Mi duda es como evito este error, he intentado comprobar que existe la tabla pero no he sido capaz.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu método boot, primero comprueba si la tabla categories (por lo que veo así se llama tu tabla) existe. Para comprobar la existencia de tu tabla debes utilizar hasTable dentro de tu método boot. Quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
if(Schema::hasTable('categories')) {
    $auxCategories = Category::orderBy("name", "asc")->get();
    View::share("auxCategories", $auxCategories);
}
```

No te olvides de importar el namespace:

```
use Schema;
```